# Drupal Token Replacement in Template File

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-templates

Can I use token replacements in Drupal template files? I'm trying this:

```
$author_uid = "[node:author:uid]";
$nid = "[node:nid]";
```

But it's not working. How can i properly use token replacements in my node.tpl.php template?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it!! This worked for me:

```
$author_uid = token_replace('[node:author:uid]', array('node' => $node));
$nid = token_replace('[node:nid]', array('node' => $node));
```

You have to pass the $node to the token_replace() function and you will then get your desired results. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for this. You've saved me hours of researching